# Wso2 API manager docker images for redhat openshift

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are trying to deploy the docker images on redhat openshift platform and was able to deploy with default Ubuntu base files

But we need the docker files align with the production environment so we need to convert the base from Ubuntu to redhat

Has anyone deployed api manager in openshift  or converted the docker images to redhat

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift is running kubernetes underneath therefore wso2 products can be deployed in OpenShift with [kubernetes membership scheme](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-artifacts/tree/master/common/kubernetes-membership-scheme) for clustering.

Converting wso2 docker images to RedHat should not be a problem. You only need to convert [dockerfile](https://github.com/wso2/docker-common/tree/master/wso2base) and [few scripts](https://github.com/wso2/docker-common/tree/master/scripts) from ubuntu to RedHat.

There are existing deployments running wso2 products on OpenShift.

Comment: Hi anuruddha thanks for the response ,we have started changing the scripts to redhat but the development goes with assumptions like in image-config.Sh there is a command called adduser --disabled--login wso2 for which in redhat we don't have disabled login command and we are not completely sure whether to keep or remove that since it is product specific.can you please suggest how to proceed on this

Comment: This is not a product specific command. This user is created to start wso2 servers. The login is disabled as a security measure and it is not mandatory to disable login to this user. If the docker containers are running in a secure environment I guess you can omit the disable--login option.